# Glimpse works locally but not on Azure

Tags: azure, glimpse

I'm running the latest version of Glimpse and running the site locally shows the Glimpse bar bottom right but not when hosted on Azure.

I've done everything in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955243/cant-get-glimpse-to-work-on-remote-iis) which says to add the following to the web.config:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
  <inspectors>
    <ignoredTypes>
      <add type="Glimpse.Mvc.Inspector.DependencyInjectionInspector, Glimpse.Mvc4"/>
    </ignoredTypes>
  </inspectors>
<runtimePolicies>
  <ignoredTypes>
    <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
  </ignoredTypes>
</runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

The official docs don't mention the inspectors node but it doesn't work when I try without it either.

I tried adding:

> ```
> <logging level="Trace" />
> ```

but can't see where that would be output.

When I go to glimpse.axd it correctly hides the warning message that I see on local:

```
Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy *This policy means that Glimpse won't run remotely.*
```

Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: by setting the loglevel to trace, a _glimpse.log_ file will be created inside the root of your web application and might then contain additional information on why the icon is still not shown. The _inspectors_ section is not needed for your case. The ignore of the _LocalPolicy_ type should do it. Do you see any kind of javascript errors in the browser console?

Comment: Thanks! That let me find out I needed to add @Html.GlimpseClient() in my _Layout.cshtml (with a using statement of Glimpse.Mvc.Html) which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was on MVC and Azure I needed to do both steps [listed here](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Troubleshooting).

Then in views/web.config add:

```
<add namespace="Glimpse.Mvc.Html" />
```

Comment: Great to hear the doco helped... Was it the compression in the end?

Comment: Yes, it was the compression issue with </body>. The inline comments in web.config didn't mention that step.

Answer (score 0):

In your Web.config add the runtimePolicy as below.

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd" >
 <runtimePolicies>
    <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </ignoredTypes>
 </runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

And then add `@Html.GlimpseClient()` to the end of your Layout page.

No idea why this second part is necessary for remote and not local, but it worked for me.